# apex:repeat two levels of related lists in a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

The following works fine for the first level ...

```
<apex:repeat var="session" value={!Event__c.Sessions__r}">
         <apex:outputText value="{!session.Name}"></apex:outputText>
</apex:repeat>
```

For the second level this is what we tried.

```
<apex:repeat var="speaker" value="{!Event__c.Sessions__r.Speakers__r}">
         <apex:outputText value="{!speaker.Name}"></apex:out>
</apex:repeat>
```

But there is a syntax error. Is this possible or does it need a controller or extension?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all It would be better to include the syntax error, to understand the issue.
I tried similar code and found you have a syntax error on your second output text.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!speaker.Name}"></apex:out>
<apex:outputText value="{!speaker.Name}"></apex:outputText>
```

Second line is what you are suppose to have.